# IndexOutOfRange Exception when working with DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm using StreamReader to access to CSV text file and read all the lines to a DataTable.

```
public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable(string filePath, int numberOfColumns)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
            tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + (col + 1).ToString()));

        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new StreamReader("C:/ProgramData/3CX/Instance1/Data/Logs/CDRLogs/cdr.log");

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var cols = line.Split(',');
            DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
            for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < cols.Length + 1; cIndex++)
            {
                dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex];
            }
            tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

Once I've added all the CSV rows to the DataTable I want to iterate through the rows and remomve unwanted rows on conditions.

```
DataTable dt = ConvertToDataTable("C:/ProgramData/3CX/Instance1/Data/Logs/CDRLogs", 4);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string duration = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            if (duration == "")
            {
                dt.Rows[i].Delete();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
        }
```

This runs just fine until I reach the last row, where it seems to be looping through a row that doesn't exist.

Anyone have an idea as to why? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where exactly you got exception? Maybe last row does not contain 2nd column? ```dt.Rows[i][1]```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never delete an element of a collection you are iterating, Even with a for cycle, you need to pay some attentions (such iterating backwards, as @Adimeus suggests).

In your code, if you delete the last row, next line you try to access to Rows[i], which does not exists any more. and even if it's not the last row, Rows[i] refers to the row following the one you deleted. Not what you want to write on console, I assume.

Comment: `< cols.Length + 1` also seems fishy, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deleting the row, you shouldn't set i=i+1 ,because amount or rows was decreased

```
        int i = 0; 
        while(i < dt.Rows.Count)
        {
            string duration = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            if (duration == "")
            {
                dt.Rows[i].Delete();
            }
            else
            {i++;}
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate trough the rows backwards to keep the indices as they are.

```
for(int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   dt.Rows[i].Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When deleting, loop *backward*, instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  ...    
  dt.Rows[i].Delete();
  ... 
}
```

Put

```
for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; --i)
{
    string duration = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();

    if (duration == "")
    {
        dt.Rows[i].Delete();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
}
```

In case you *have to* loop *forward* for whatever reason, modify the loop into

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ) // do not increment here
{
    string duration = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();

    if (duration == "")
    {
        dt.Rows[i].Delete();
    }
    else
        i += 1; // ... but increment here 

    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Increment `i` at the end of the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; )
{
    string duration = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
    if (duration == "")
    {
        dt.Rows[i].Delete();
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do when I have to delete elements from the collection I'm iterating is to save the rows delete in a different collection.
Something like this, for your case:

```
int i = 0; // if you need to dump also the number of the row
List<DataRow> toDelete = new List<DataRow>();
foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
{
    string duration = row[1].ToString();
    if (duration == "")
    {
        toDelete.Add(row);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + row[1].ToString());
    i++;
}
foreach (var rowToDelete in toDelete)
    row.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

DataTable dt = ConvertToDataTable("C:/ProgramData/3CX/Instance1/Data/Logs/CDRLogs", 4);

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string duration = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        if (duration == "")
        {
            dt.Rows[i].Delete();
            continue;                //Not printing deleted objects. So line after IF block won'nt exist.
        }
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
    }
```